# How to generate serial data that doesn't use assembly reference in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way I can remove the assembly reference and just make the BinaryFormatter assume it is the local assembly? The Assembly reference here is `ASCOM.BHOProxy.Connector`, and I sometimes have a problem where it can't find the assembly when deserializing (see another question where I asked for details on the problem itself: [BinaryFormatter can't find 'Assembly' upon deserialize in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13821198/258482))

> PORTCOMR??j???????       ?   ?????       ??   [ASCOM.BHOProxy.Connector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=74643865492aa2e6??   ¶Connector.ProxReturn?   ?Call   ReturnVal?isException?? ?Connector.ProxCall?   ??       ? ??   ?Connector.ProxCall?   ?Name?Args?BindingFlags?Time??? ?System.Reflection.?   ??   ?Unpark        ?   ??????System.Reflection.BindingFlags?   value__ ?  ???V??????       ?      PORTCOMS

Comment: How is this question different from your other question?

Comment: Here I'm asking how to get around it by not including assembly data, there I'm asking how to make it find the assembly.